# Laptop Submerged in Water Overnight (flood)

Tags: windows-10, laptop, help-files

I know I have to turn off my laptop when accidents with water happen. My room was flooded the other night and i only noticed in the morning that my laptop was submerged in water.

When I put it on absorbent cloths in an attempt to dry it out, I noticed that the screen light is flickering although it is turned off.

Do I still have hope for my laptop?? To retrieve files at least?

Answer (score 1):

> screen light is flickering although it is turned off.

This is not a good sign and indicates the laptop was electrically damaged inside.

> Do I still have hope for my laptop?? To retrieve files at least

The hard drive might be fine. A service person should be able to put it in a carrier and retrieve files. This should work. It depends on the total damage, but I think this is a hopeful idea.

It is probably worth your while to take the machine to a local service shop and have it assessed. Do not turn the machine on at all. Leave it and let a service person determine the next step.

Comment: The device was submerged in water, with power to the device, when means power was provided to the HDD more than likely.  The device unlikely is watertight, which means water reached the HDD, which means it reached the potentially exposed PCB.

Comment: I think that is possible (hence my guarded language) but the physical drive container is pretty well sealed, so a local service person might be able to recover data. I did touch up that portion of my answer.

Comment: So many technical terms, but I think I understand. Thank you! I would get it checked. ‍♀️